# list of all variable names from a NetCDF dataset, in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm using the RNetCDF package in R.
I'm trying to get a list of all variables 
names from an imported .nc datasets (I can 
easily get the vector of values from the 
few variables whose names I know, but I only 
know a small subset of all the variables names).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the `ncdf` pacakge which I found to be much easier to install than the `RNetCDF` package across operating systems (notably Linux and MacOS). To get the list of variables you simply:

```
library(ncdf)
nc = open.ncdf('example.nc')
variables = names(nc[['var']])
```